# Trying to create a button that will change the font family

Tags: javascript, html, button, random

I am working on an assignment that requires buttons. Am looking to create a button that changes fonts at random from a list. I have a button that doesn't work and a list that does. Any recommendations?

```
<p id="sentance">Lets try changing the font!</p>

<select onchange="myFunction(this);" size="13">
  <option>Georgia</option>
  <option>Palatino Linotype</option>
  <option>Book Antiqua</option>
  <option>Times New Roman</option>
  <option>Arial</option>
  <option>Helvetica</option>
  <option>Arial Black</option>
  <option>Impact</option>
  <option>Lucida Sans Unicode</option>
  <option>Tahoma</option>
  <option>Verdana</option>
  <option>Courier New</option>
  <option>Lucida Console</option>
</select>

<script>
function myFunction(selectTag) {
  var listValue = selectTag.options[selectTag.selectedIndex].text;
  document.getElementById("sentance").style.fontFamily = listValue;
}
</script>
```

```
<button id='FontFamily'>Change Style!</button>

<script>
    document.getElementById('FontFamily').onclick = changeFontFamily;
    var currentFontFamily = "Monaco" 

    function changeFontFamily() {
        if (currentFontFamily == "Monaco") {
            document.body.style.fontFamily = "Times New Roman";
            currentFontFamily = "Times New Roman"
        } else {
            document.body.style.fontFamily = "Monaco";
            currentFontFamily = "Monaco"
        }
        return currentFontFamily
    }

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd make the button select random fonts.

Keep in mind, if your browser doesn't know a font (you specify), it will use its default font instead. This is why you might not always see a font change happen when you click the `Change Style` button while running the code snippet below.

```js
// For selecting a random number in a range:
function randomNumberBetween(iLowest,iHighest)
{
 var iChoices = iHighest - iLowest + 1;
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * iChoices + iLowest);
}

// Fonts with spaces need quotes in CSS
function quoteFontsContainingSpaces(font)
{
  if (font.includes(" "))
  {
    font = `"${font}"`;
  }
  return font;
}

let sentence = document.getElementById("sentence");
let selectorFontList = document.getElementById("selectorFontList");

function onFontChangeEventHandler(e)
{
  let fontString = quoteFontsContainingSpaces(this.value);
  sentence.style.fontFamily = fontString;
}

selectorFontList.addEventListener("change", onFontChangeEventHandler);

let btnChangeRandom = document.getElementById("btnChangeRandom");

btnChangeRandom.addEventListener('click', function()
{
  let rIndex = randomNumberBetween(0,selectorFontList.length - 1);
  selectorFontList.selectedIndex = `${rIndex}`;
  let event = new Event('change');
  selectorFontList.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

```css
#selectorFontList
{
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p id="sentence">Lets try changing the font!</p>
<button id='btnChangeRandom'>Change Style!</button>
<br>
<select id="selectorFontList" size="13">
  <option>Georgia</option>
  <option>Palatino Linotype</option>
  <option>Book Antiqua</option>
  <option>Times New Roman</option>
  <option>Arial</option>
  <option>Helvetica</option>
  <option>Arial Black</option>
  <option>Impact</option>
  <option>Lucida Sans Unicode</option>
  <option>Tahoma</option>
  <option>Verdana</option>
  <option>Courier New</option>
  <option>Lucida Console</option>
</select>
```